# Html Value Binding

Tags: html, vue.js

im working with .Net and Vue and I cant really bind a value in a label

```
   <li v-for="restaurant in vHolidays.data" >
                        <form id="1">
                            <div>
                                <label >{{restaurant.restaurantId}}</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control"   value=HERE>

                            </div>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-block" @click="test()">Modificar</button>
                        </form>



                    </li>
```

In "HERE" I want to put the same as {{restaurant.restaurantId}} that alredy works .
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `v-bind` directive to bind tag attribute values to Vue expression:

`<input type="text" class="form-control" v-bind:value="restaurant.restaurantId">`

or its shorthand `:`:

`<input type="text" class="form-control" :value="restaurant.restaurantId">`

Read more about this directive here: [link](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/index.html#v-bind)